# DIMM cards + what is the meaning of - Configured Clock Speed

Tags: linux, redhat, memory, memory-usage, dmidecode

we add the following DIMM card in our DELL server ( 16G memory ) , OS is RHEL 7.6 version

as we can see the speed is  - **2400MHz**

but the - Configured Clock Speed: is only **1866MHz**

so I guess that value as - **1866MHz** , is because we set the DIMM card in socket that maybe limited the speed ?

so regarding to that we have few Question's:

1. what are the consequences when memory speed is lowest then what DIMM card can work with **2400MHz**
   is it something that have meaning about read/write to memory RAM? / else?
2. the **1866MHz** that we get , is only because DIMMs combination on socket?
3. how to get the max **2400MHz** ? what is the right approach about DIMM's location ?

here the results from `dmidecode`

```
Server is Dell PowerEdge R730 and memories are:

Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 16384 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 3
    Locator: A9
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered)
    Speed: 2400 MHz
    Manufacturer: 002C0632002C
    Serial Number: 1B42681B
    Asset Tag: 001808A0
    Part Number: 18ASF2G72PDZ-2G3D1
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1866 MHz
    Minimum Voltage:  1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage:  1.2 V
    Configured Voltage:  1.2 V
```

from DELL HW document we can see that

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is because we set the DIMM card in socket that maybe limited the speed
> ?

Yes

> what are the consequences when memory speed is lowest then what DIMM
> card can work with 2400MHz is it something that have meaning about
> read/write to memory RAM? / else?

The only difference is performance, it's not going as fast as it could.

> the 1866MHz that we get , is only because DIMMs combination on socket?

Very possibly but without knowing the FULL spec of your memory layout we can't say, but...

> how to get the max 2400MHz ? what is the right approach about DIMM's
> location ?

This is a very useful guide to how to lay out your memory and what speeds you'll get as you fill the slots - [Clicky](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-uk/poweredge-r730/r730_ompublication/sample-memory-configurations?guid=guid-dc8f9ffb-7a9c-43ae-b25c-b2079fc6a490&lang=en-us)

Comment: I not sure about but I need to ask , according to the doc we can see that we have 3 speed  , so if for example we used the first and second socket then we get - 2133 , but if we also used the 3 socket , then we get - 1866? am I correct here ?

Comment: Every server has a 'fill order' - which slots to use first, follow that guide and you'll get the best performance with the DIMMs you have.